# Can I delete local copy of Xcode archive?

Tags: xcode, backup, archive

I'm about to wipe my MacBook Air and am wondering if I need to back up my local archives of app versions that I've already uploaded (including symbols) to the App Store. When I install Xcode (on a clean install of macOS) and log in with my developer account, will Xcode automatically download and show these archives and their crashes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do need to manually backup your local archives. These are not stored in a cloud for you to pull down on a new system. Crash logs and dSYM files *do* come from Apple's servers, however.